# Bridge Edge Loops snapping to vertice instead of the object itself?

Tags: modeling

[image: selected vertices in 1st picture as shown to join using bridge edge loops.]

[image: one side merged into the solid smoothly, the other side snapped to vertices showing that weird squarish edge. Could somebody help me out? What could be the problem?]

I selected vertices in 1st picture as shown to join using bridge edge loops. One side merged into the solid smoothly, the other side snapped to vertices showing that weird squarish edge. Could somebody help me out? What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, this is not the bridge issue, check your Face Orientation, my guess is that either left or right side has flipped normals and when 2 flipped normals meet, they make this

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:
[image]
[image]

Go to the top side of your 3d viewport and select this:
[image]

Your mesh will surely have some blue and red parts (your mesh is supposed to be blue on the outside)
[image]

So select all the Red faces and press Alt+N and select Flip to Flip your normals, or try selecting all faces and using "Recalculate Outside"...

Now your subdivision will work as supposed